# How to find contents of a file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep, ls, cat

How do I display content of files with name containing letter 'a' in it?
I tried
`cat|ls|grep 'a'`

Comment: Do you mean files that would match the glob pattern `*a*`?

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
find . -type f -name '*a*' -exec cat {} \;
```

Comment: In some situations, the shell will need elements of your answer escaped, specifically the end of the `find` command may need to be `'{}' \+`

Comment: @user1404316, `+` is not special in any shell. `{}` is not special in any shell of the Bourne or csh families. It's special in rc/es/fish. But then if we have to cover for those shells many answers here would not work either as for instance `%` is also special in fish and `"` is not a quoting operator in rc/es. And backslash is not a quoting operator in `rc` either, so your `\+` wouldn't work there. When the shell is not specified, POSIX sh or compatible is usually implied here.

Answer (score 2):

The `less` pager has a feature that allows browsing multiple files and jumping among them, so if all files are in the same directory `less *a*` will initially open the first, and you can at any time advance to the next file by typing `:n` or return to the previous file by typing `:p`. Typing `=` at any time will display the current file's name. The `less` pager has many other useful documented yet un-commonly used features. From within the program, type `h` for a long mutliple-page cheat sheet.

```
find -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '*a*' -exec less '{}' +
```

Comment: It would be better to call `less` from `-exec` to support filenames that contains spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If all files are located in the same directory, this short version will do it:

```
cat *a*
```

In case of *funny* filenames starting with '-' a './' should be prefix:

```
cat ./*a*
```

Directories with `a` will result in a non harmful error message.

Comment: That'll also try to `cat` non-files (directories, for example).

Comment: @Kusalananda, a directory is one many different types of files. Of all the different types of files, it's probably the one (along with sockets) that you're least likely to want to `cat`, but you may still want to cat devices or fifos or symlinks to regular files (all of which would be excluded by `find -type f` or `zsh`'s `cat ./*(.)`) depending on context.

Comment: It would fail for file names starting with `-` though. You may prefer `cat ./*a*` or `cat -- *a*`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `./` is good. I've added it.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are located in one directory you can use

for i in *a*; do ( echo $i && cat $i && echo " "); done

to show all the files. Nevertheless you are still able to remember which output comes from which file and there is a seperation of the individual file output.

Comment: What's the subshell for?

Comment: There may be things that are not regularly files that matches that pattern. You also need to double quote the variable expansions to support multi-word names.

Answer (score 0):

To output the content of all *regular* files in the current directory whose name contains the `a` character:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -name '*a*' -type f -exec cat {} +
```

Though with several `find` implementations (including the GNU one on your Ubuntu), that would exclude files whose name contains byte sequences that don't form valid characters in the current locale.

With some `find` implementations, you can use `-depth 1` instead of the standard `! -name . -prune`. Some others (like GNU `find`) have `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` (though `-maxdepth 1` is enough here as depth 0 is `.` which is excluded by both `-type f` and `-name '*a*'`).

The invalid character issue could be alleviated by using `zsh` and:

```
cat ./*a*(D.)
```

Which would also have the benefit of reporting an error if there's no matching file and sorting the list of files so the output is less random.

If you also want to include symlinks to  regular files, add a `-L` option to `find` or `-` in the zsh glob qualifier.

If you want to exclude hidden files, add a `! -name '.*'` to `find` or remove the `D` from zsh's glob qualifier.

Note that `cat` concatenates those files. If `a1` contains `foo` without a trailing newline character (which shouldn't happen if `a1` were a proper text file) and `a2` contained `bar`, the output would be `foobar`.

To include the file names, you could use `grep '^' /dev/null` instead of `cat` which would prepend each line with the name of the file. Or `grep -n '^' /dev/null` to also include line numbers.

With the GNU implementation of `head` (as found on your Ubuntu), you can use `head -vc-0` which would add a

```
===> ./file_with_a <===
```

header and an empty line between each file.

Comment: In some situations, the shell will need elements of your answer escaped, specifically the end of the `find` command may need to be `'{}' \+`

Comment: @user1404316, `+` is not special in any shell. `{}` is not special in any shell of the Bourne or csh families. It's special in rc/es/fish. But then if we have to cover for those shells many answers there would not work either as for instance `%` is also special in `fish` and `"` is not a quoting operator in rc/es. And backslash is not a quoting operator in `rc` either, so your `\+` wouldn't work there. When the shell is not specified, POSIX sh or compatible is usually implied here.